# Install BIOS for Dell Inspiron 1564

Tags: bios, dell-inspiron

my labtob doesn't power on (when i click the power button the lamp flashes and it doesn't power on), i went to a technician and he said that the bios is corrupted, and he want to install a new bios not update.

please advise how can i install a new bios, because all the files i found was for updating bios not installing a new one, and to update the bios i need to power on the laptop first.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't open"?

Comment: @Renan, question updated.

Comment: @Msaleh - When your laptop doesn't turn on is it on battery power?

Comment: @Ramhound, both charger and battery are connected and it doesn't turn on, i removed the battery and tried another charger and same behavior, the lamp flashes then it doesn't turn on.

Comment: @Msaleh - If the BIOS is corrupt you don't have a great deal of options.  Unless you can explain the technician was going to do exactly we can't really help.  I assume the technician was from Dell, and because of that fact, he has special tools to replace the BIOS.  You won't be able to do this without Dell.  **My guess they were going to just replace the motherboard to be honest.**

Answer (score 0):

You could try to unplug the battery and remove the power-cord and press the power-button for a few seconds (10 should do).

This will reset the BIOS to default. I know this is over a year old thread, but maybe it helps some other people.

I had the similar problem few days ago and this did a good job ;)

Comment: Is yours a Dell? Where did you find out about this trick?